# RMWC Select Component won't display selected value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am attempting to use the `Select` component from `rmwc 5.6.0` but the `Select` component will not display the selected value. This exact code worked for `rmwc 3.0.11`.

This is how I am using the component:

```
<Select
    label="Status"
    name="status"
    onChange={this.onChange}
    outlined
    key={1}
    options={['All', 'Accepted', 'Ordered']} />
```

When I select an option, it will do what it has to do, but the `Select` component will just stay blank as if I haven't selected anything and when I click outside of it, the label goes back to being "Status"

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<select label="Manual" value={get value from state}
    onChange={(event) => {
        // set event.target.value to state
    }
}>
    <option value="cookies">Cookies</option>
    <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
    <option value="icecream">Icecream</option>
</select>
```

Change the value in `onChange`.